# Quick Books API playground - development application can only subscribe to sandbox company

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

While playing with https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA, I faced with an error:

[image]

It appeared recently, before I havn't had it. What's the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

> developer.intuit.com

You can see an option to create a sandbox company file there , i just found it now, And thanks for the poor support from intuit to make us wait for 2 3 days to identify the new change

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCxZH.png

Comment: where is that exactly?

Comment: once I connected, is there any to find out what the Access Token Duration is?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp am also checking about it, It seems like accesstoken is malformed, will post here if i find something useful, please share the same if u do

Comment: actually i think access token is valid for 6 months, i once read a post regarding it , but not sure, my problem is iam getting malformed access token from intuit.